# Select file destination CrossFilePicker.Current.SaveFile(fileData) Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, filepicker, xamarin.uwp

I'm using `Xamarin.Dialog.Plugin.FilePicker` to pick a text file, and it works for me, but when I want to save a text file using `CrossFilePicker.Current.SaveFile(fileData)`, a file destination picker is not openning.

Any sugestion to save a file on a destination from my choose using Xamarin Forms?

Comment: Did you set the permission in your manifest? On which platform was it fail?

Comment: Thanks @GraceFeng-MSFT for replying!

Yes, I've setted the manifest with READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, but not working yet!

Answer (score 0):

I think the SaveFile() is not doing what you expect. When you look e.g. at the Android implementation, it only saves the file to the external storage folder for the app. It's not meant to open a "save file" requester.

The real solution depends on your use case. If you want to open the file in another application, you have to implement a ContentProvider and open a content:// URL that your app handles, by using Intent.ActionView or similar. There currently is no Xamarin Plugin for doing this.